# Adding a font awesome icon on a Menu Tab

Tags: php, yii, font-awesome

I have the following code:

```
<?php $this ->widget('application.extensions.mbmenu.MbMenu',array(
    'items'=>array(
         array('label'=>'Home','url'=>array('/site/index')),
```

.....

I am trying to bring in font-awesome icon and place it next to the Home label.
   Something like this. I am not sure exactly how to write code so that php welcomes font awesome icon. Thank you for all help. It is greatly appreciated.

```
array('label'=>'Home<icon-fa-home icon-3x>')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you import fontawesome css and font files inside your layout. Next, you can do this in your code:

```
array('label'=>'Home <span class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></span>');
```

Or

```
array('label'=>'Home <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></i>');
```

[Here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) is more information about fontawesome.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Doing that simply outputs                                      Home <span class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></span>    I do have the style sheet for fontawesome css active as I could use it when it is simply html format. Any other way you could think of for embedding in php code?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... Strange why method descriibed by @hamed not working. Try add this paramter to item:

`'itemOptions' => array('class'=>'fa fa-home fa-3x'),`

This should add classes to link. If it will works that mean something wrong with creating custom menu wiget. But it realy strange because:

```
array('label'=>'Home <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></i>');
```

should work.